# AWS Cloud Formation !Sub & !Ref functions inside AWS::Serverless::Function Policies

Tags: yaml, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have been using the !Sub function in my CloudFormation Yaml templates just fine. And when used it as an object property value it works for me

```
Object:
  Property1: !Sub some-value-with-a-${variable}-in-it
```

The value of variable gets replaced as expected.

However, I can't figure out how to use the !Sub function in an element of a string array

```
Array:
  - !Sub some-value-with-a-${variable}-in-it
```

That array element just gets ignored.

I am trying this in the context of a SAM template creating a AWS::Serverless::Function type resource. The Policies property can take an array of strings:

```
lambda:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri: api
    FunctionName: !Sub api-${MyStageName}
    Handler: Lambda:Api.Function::HandleAsync
    Runtime: dotnetcore1.0
    Policies: 
    - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
    - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/some-policy
    - arn:aws:iam::123456789:policy/another-policy
```

The !Sub function works in the `FunctionName` property in this example. But I only end up with 2 Policies attached to my generated role - `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` and `arn:aws:iam::123456789:policy/another-policy`. The one including the `!Sub` function gets ignored.

I have tried options like putting the function on a new line:

```
Array:
  - 
    !Sub some value with a ${variable} in it
```

Can anyone help?

## Update

@Tom Melo pointed out that this is not a array problem so I have adjusted my question.

Further investigation has revealed it is not a Cloud Formation issue exactly, but very specific to the `AWS::Serverless::Function` resource type, and the `Policies` property within in. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the `Policies` property is so flexible in what it can accept. It can accept strings referring to policy names or Arns, and it can also accept policy documents describing new policy. I suspect this means it is not able to support the functions.

Comment: There should not be a difference in using `!Sub` with an array item or a mapping value. This seems to be a bug and should be reported as such. I'd try to quote the scalar after `!Sub`; maybe it's a parser bug and if so, that could be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Quotes didn't work so I will try logging a bug

Comment: Issue created: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=261756

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, there's nothing wrong with !Sub function in a array of elements.

I have tried to create the following stack on Cloudformation and it worked:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'IAM Roles Template'

Parameters:
  ArnBase:
    Type: String
    Default: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/
  AWSLambdaFullAccess:
    Type: String
    Default: AWSLambdaFullAccess
  AmazonSESFullAccess:
    Type: String
    Default: AmazonSESFullAccess    

Resources:

  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole          
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: CloudFormationFullAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action: "cloudformation:*"
                Resource: "*"    
      ManagedPolicyArns:        
        - !Sub ${ArnBase}${AWSLambdaFullAccess}        
        - !Sub ${ArnBase}${AmazonSESFullAccess}
        - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/CustomAmazonGlacierReadOnlyAccess
```

That should work using SAM either...

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks for ruling that out. Looks like my question needs to be more specific. Maybe it's SAM, or maybe it's the policies property on the Serverless Function type. I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

The `AWS::Serverless::Function` resource type supports several ways of configuring access.

1. Refer to policies directly via the `Policies` property and have the framework create a role that has those policies.
2. The `Role` property can refer to a role which already contains policies.

I was using option 1, but option 2 proves to be a way around the issues with `!Sub` function.

Creating a role explicitly with the policies we want using the `AWS::IAM::Role` means we can use the `!Sub` function within the `ManagedPolicyArns` property. For example

```
role:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    ...
    ManagedPolicyArns:
      - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/some-policy
    ...
lambda:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    ...
    Role: !GetAtt role.Arn
    ...
```